# Open a worksheet in multiple windows and remember them the next time. How to do?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I would like to set it so multiple windows will be opened automatically every time I open that worksheet.

It should remember the locations of the windows, which area the windows show, zoom levels etc.

How could I achieve this? Do I need to resort to macro? Thank you.

Comment: Isn't this behavior is by default?

Comment: @Lee The behavior is strange. Sometimes it wont work. It appears if I completely close Excel and reopen Excel, and then open that worksheet, or if I restart the computer, it won't open multiple windows. Also some settings are not remembered, for example the size of each window.

Comment: It happened again just now. It is able to open multiple windows the first time I re-open the workbook (while keeping Excel opened). However it opens one window only the second time. It is weird.